# How to divide a grep test in to a parallel task

Tags: c, regex, multithreading, grep, parallel-processing

I want to write a program that just like `grep` command to deal with my sql file. I hope it can use all of my cores when it working. Using MPI or just Pthreads, it doesn't matter. But, *How can I divide the file in to 4 files?* I mean, if I have a txt file with 700mb size, how to make every thread deal with 1/4 of that file.

In my opinion, I need know how many lines of this file, then, set different file offset per thread. Is it a good way, and how to get the number of total lines?

maybe get how many lines the file have will take a long time:

```
madper@myhost ~ % time wc -l lineitem.tbl
6001215 lineitem.tbl
wc -l lineitem.tbl  0.20s user 0.40s system 4% cpu 12.996 total
```

Comment: Without having the data its hard to test how long a `wc -l` would take. That should return the number of lines (i.e.: how long does it take?)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [GNU parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel)?

Comment: @JonasWielicki It will take a long time. I edit my question, just add the time that `wc -l` takes.  Thank you~

Comment: @Pascal Thank you very much! But I need write one for building skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do isn't very easy.  Frameworks like Google's MapReduce and Apache Hadoop have been created to handle problems like this.  In the general case, splitting up an arbitrary large file for arbitrary parallel processing is a difficult problem, and it's best to use a dedicated framework for this task.  But in your case, since you seem to have very specific requirements, you might be able to do something like:

Split the file into N chunks (where N = number of cores).  Obviously, this won't respect line boundaries, so you'll need a "splitter" routine which searches for the next new line character in each chunk.  (This may be tricky to get right and avoid overlapping, but it's basically what Hadoop or MapReduce does.)  You can then process each chunk in parallel.

Of course, this might not be effective as you think.  If the entire file doesn't fit in memory, you're going to run into I/O problems.  Just because you are parallelizing CPU usage doesn't necessarily mean you're parallelizing I/O.  This is why distributed processing frameworks usually also split data across multiple hard drives or cluster nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try now. I think can set different file offset to avoid load all this file to memory.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your runtime statistics look like the program is I/O limited. 
There is a huge amount of spare CPU. So making the CPU part parallel is unlikely to make much positive difference. In fact, it might make it worse because disk caching might be less effective.

There was a long running series on solving a similar problem by Tim Bray at http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/09/20/Wide-Finder

He got help from a lot of people to investigate a similar sort of problem (scanning system logs), so you might find some ready made help there.

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope you have fun investigating solutions.

Comment: Maybe I can creat a thread just for read data from file. Then, put the data into three buffers, and creat three threads to deal with the data. I hope that can avoid disk caching hit rate down